# How to save page edits on a ReactJS site when navigating from page to page

Tags: reactjs, state, single-page-application, aws-amplify

I have a basic ReactJS app with 5 pages in what I think is an SPA (every page shares a common header element with the menu), each page has it's own route and I'm making the menu items like this:

```
<Link to="/save">Save</Link>
```

To make the question really simple, let's say on one page the user enters his name into a text box.  Then the user clicks on another page and then clicks back onto the first page.  Well, when we get back to the first page, the text box is empty.  What is the most common way to solve this problem with ReactJS?  I want to not have had the text box get emptied.  In actuality I will have quite a few things I don't want to disappear when switching between views and I'd rather not have to write code to recreate the state of everything, but just have it still be there.

This is of course a very basic question.  Even just giving me a good google search string to point me in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe store the value in a persisting state manager? If not, maybe localStorage?

Comment: I have a feeling there are tools within ReactJS that can do this. There is something called  Context that might be it and maybe I'm not using it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you describe is similar to `keep-alive` in `vue.js`.

you can use redux to save page data when `componentWillUnmount`,and get page date when  `componentDidMount`.

or you can try this [React Keep Alive](https://github.com/StructureBuilder/react-keep-alive/blob/master/README.zh-CN.md)

Comment: I think that keep-alive sounds like the most direct answer to my question but it's not used much it seems.  I looked at some Redux info online and at first glance it is overkill, but I will research it more.  There is also just the possibility of hiding and unhiding HTML to accomplish the same (display: none | block;)